# laravel relationships belongsToMany with conditions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, relational-database

I am have 2 models, a Project model and a User models, a User can have many projects,

The relationship looks a little like this,

```
public function myProjects($archived = false) {

        if ($archived) return $this->belongsToMany('Project', 'project_user', 'user_id', 'project_id')->withPivot(['last_opened as last_opened','role as role']);
        else           return $this->belongsToMany('Project', 'project_user', 'user_id', 'project_id')->where('projects.archived_at', '=', "0000-00-00 00:00:00")->withPivot(['last_opened as last_opened','role as role']);

}
```

A Project also belongs to an Organisation, this is where my problem starts, the projects that are returned here also include Projects that belong to Organisation that have been soft deleted, and I don't want it too, is there a way I can select only the projects with organisations that don;t have a deleted at date?

Comment: `has` / `whereHas` in Eloquent are what you need.

Comment: Would that be applied to the relationship i.e in the function, or applied after I have called that function?

Comment: Both are possible. You could have an `archivedProjects` relationship that does `return $this->belongsToMany(...)->whereHas(...)`, or you could have a `projects` relationship and do `whereHas` on `$user->projects()->whereHas(...)` on the fly.